# jest change mocked value at later stage

Tags: jestjs

I have a mock where it sets up a return value before all my tests. But I was wondering if you could update a value in the test itself. As you can see I want to just update the boolean value of mockedIsloading, without calling the entire  mockedLoadStatus.mockReturnValue({...}) again in my test with a new isLoading value of true this time around.

Would be nice to just be able to call mockedIsloading.mockReturnValueOnce(true) but this does not seem to work.

```
import {
  loadStatus,
} from 'pathToMyFile'

jest.mock('pathToMyFile')
const mockedLoadStatus jest.mocked(loadStatus)

const mockedMutate = jest.fn()
const mockedIsLoading = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false)

beforeAll(() => {
  mockedLoadStatus.mockReturnValue({
    mutate: mockedMutate,
    isLoading: mockedIsloading,
  })
})


test('my test', () => {
  mockedIsloading.mockReturnValueOnce(true)
  render(<Wrapper />)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "doesn't work"? I mean this works OK:

```js
const mockedLoadStatus = jest.fn();

const mockedMutate = jest.fn()
const mockedIsLoading = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false)

beforeAll(() => {
  mockedLoadStatus.mockReturnValue({
    mutate: mockedMutate,
    isLoading: mockedIsLoading,
  })
})

test('some test', () => {
  expect(mockedLoadStatus().isLoading()).toBeFalsy();
})

test('my test', () => {
  mockedIsLoading.mockReturnValueOnce(true)
  expect(mockedLoadStatus().isLoading()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(mockedLoadStatus().isLoading()).toBeFalsy();
})
```

Or am I missing something :) ?